# Smooth mapping between Manifolds

Tags: manifolds, riemannian-geometry

Given:

- two Euclidean spaces $\mathcal{P},\mathcal{P'}$ (with their usual smooth structure) and a injective smooth mapping $f:\mathcal{P}\to\mathcal{P'}$
- a Riemannian manifold $(\mathcal{M}\subset \mathcal{P},g_\mathcal{M})$ (the tangent spaces of $\mathcal{M}$ lies in $\mathcal{P}$)
- a space $\mathcal{N} = f(\mathcal{M}) \subset \mathcal{P'}$. $f$ is an isomorphism $\mathcal{M}$ and $\mathcal{N}$ and $f$ is $C^\infty$ on $\mathcal{M}$

Is it direct to say that:

1. $\mathcal{N}$ is a smooth manifold
2. For $x\in\mathcal{M}$, $\mathcal{T}_{f(x)}\mathcal{N}= f(\mathcal{T}_x \mathcal{M})$ (tangent spaces)
3. For $y\in  \mathcal{N}$, $u_1,u_2\in \mathcal{T}_y \mathcal{N}$, the metric tensor $g_\mathcal{N}$ defined by:
   $$g_\mathcal{N}(u_1,u_2) \triangleq g_\mathcal{M}(f^{-1}(u_1),f^{-1}(u_2))$$
   is such that $(\mathcal{N},g_\mathcal{N})$ is a Riemanian Manifold with:

   - Same notion of distance $d_\mathcal{M}(x_1,x_2) = d_\mathcal{N}(f(x_1),f(x_2))$
   - Same notion of geodesic $\gamma_\mathcal{M}(x_1\to x_2) = f^{-1}(\gamma_\mathcal{N}(f(x_1)\to f(x_2))$

Or do I need additional properties to prove these points ? My goal is to use the mapping $f$ to endow $\mathcal{N}$ with a Riemannian structure. A solution could be to use local maps to show properties 1., 2. and 3. but it is maybe unnecessary in this "simple" case ?

[Edited following comments of Anthony Carapetis]

Comment: A couple clarifications would be nice: $\mathcal P$ and $\mathcal P'$ are just Euclidean spaces with their usual smooth structure, right? Also, how are you defining a $C^\infty$ diffeomorphism $f: \mathcal M \to \mathcal N$ if you haven't yet established a smooth structure on $\mathcal N$? Also your $f^{-1}(u_i)$ should be $f^*(u_i)$.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis In general, $f^*(u_i)$ is the way of pulling a metric back, but since $\mathcal{T}\mathcal{M}\subset\mathcal{P}$, $f^{-1}(u_1)$ could make sense as well. However, the identifications $\mathcal{TM}\cong\widetilde{\mathcal{P}}\subset\mathcal{P}$ remains unclear.

Comment: @gofvonx: it doesn't seem to make much sense to pull back the vectors using $f^{-1}$ - is this really what you want? $g_\mathcal N$ defined this way will in general not be bilinear...

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis I have edited the post following your first comment. Sorry for the lack of clarity.

Comment: $f^{-1}$ is still linear. I have changed bijection into isomorphism to reflect this fact so $g_\mathcal{N}$ is bilinear. I am not sure if I can use $f$ to move the tangent spaces (point 2.). If it is the case, I should be able to pull back the vectors using $f^{-1}$.

Comment: If $f$ is an isomorphism, it also is an diffeomorphism and thus the vector (sub-)spaces $\mathcal{M},\mathcal{N}$, endowed with the usual smooth structure on finite-dimensional vector spaces, are diffeomorphic. So as far as I can see, you can pull the metric back as usual.

Comment: Ok thanks. Yes both spaces are diffeomorphic wrt the usual smooth structure but I wasn't 100% sure that it was enough to pull back the Riemanian metric (I am mainly into computer science and I lack of formalism when it comes to deal with Riemanian geometry)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f$ is a linear bijection $\mathcal M \to \mathcal N$ then it extends to a linear isomorphism from $V =\operatorname{span} \mathcal M$ to  $V' = \operatorname{span} \mathcal N$. Since these subspaces are the only relevant parts of $\mathcal P, \mathcal P'$ to the manifold structure (tangent vectors will also lie in these subspaces), we can transport all structure from $\mathcal M$ to $\mathcal N$ via the ambient space identification $V \simeq V'$ as you describe.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Using $V$ and $V'$ identification seems indeed to make sense and allows me to explain better why I can transport the structure !